# LINQ2SQL Database providers

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have heard that LINQ2SQL has been written to support multiple database vendor providers however for internal political reasons at MS, only SQL Server has been supported.

Is this a fair summary of the situation, and if so has a timetable been released as to when other databases will be supported?

I am aware of Matt Warren's [BUILDING AN IQUERYABLE PROVIDER](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx) series on the wayward weblog, but I would prefer not to build something now that will be released (probably better than I will do it) later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) (and [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx)), you can look here also a [Sample Entity Framework Provider for Oracle](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider), and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/adonetefx/) are more examples about creating Data Providers for EF.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework has support for multiple database providers. There are no plans to expose or implement additional LINQ to SQL database providers.